# Prevenir NULL en múltiples JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito que la consulta SQL no devuelva filas con campos `null` cuando el campo `productos.id` no exista en la tabla.

La consulta SQL es la siguiente:

```
SELECT productos.id,productos.nombre, productos.descripcion, productos.precio, tipos.nombre AS tipo_nombre, tipos.id as id_tipo,categorias.id as categoria_id, categorias.nombre as categoria_nombre, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT( detalle_productos.dimensiones)) AS dimensiones 
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN tipos ON productos.id_tipo = tipos.id 
INNER JOIN detalle_productos ON productos.id = detalle_productos.id_producto 
INNER JOIN categorias on tipos.id_categoria=categorias.id 
WHERE 
productos.id =1
```

Si `producto.id` existe que devuelva lo solicitado (actualmente funciona). En el caso que no exista me está devolviendo 1 fila con todos los campos `null` y me gustaría que si no existe no devuelva ninguna fila.

Si pruebo con el `1` me retorna los datos, ya que existe en la tabla `productos`, pero si pruebo con el id `700000` me retorna 1 fila con todos los campos `null` y necesito que si no existe no devuelva ninguna fila.

Esta es la definición de las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE productos ( id int PRIMARY KEY NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar (150) not null, descripcion varchar (10000) not null,
precio int not null, dimension varchar (500), id_tipo int not null,   
FOREIGN KEY (id_tipo) REFERENCES tipos(id) )

create table categorias ( id int PRIMARY KEY not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre varchar (50) not null UNIQUE ) 

CREATE TABLE tipos( id int PRIMARY KEY NOT null AUTO_INCREMENT, nombre
varchar (50) UNIQUE, id_categoria int not null, FOREIGN KEY
(id_categoria) REFERENCES categorias(id) 

CREATE TABLE detalle_productos( id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT
null, id_producto int not null, color varchar(100) not null,
dimensiones varchar(500) not null, stock int not null, color_type
varchar (500) not null, imagen varchar(5000) not null,
imagen_Secondary varchar(5000) not null, html_color varchar(50) not
null, FOREIGN KEY (id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id) )
```

Comment: En vez de `inner join`, utiliza `left join` en el join que no quieres nulls. `left` hará que solo salgan resultados si la tabla a la izquierda del `join` tiene valor, `right join` hace exactamente lo contrario, cogiendo valores solo si la tabla de la derecha tiene valor.

Comment: Lo intente con left y left outer, en ambos hubo el mismo resultado

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar algunos datos para poder reproducir tu problema con facilidad? Por ejemplo, vendría bien la definición de las tablas.

Comment: Por ejemplo, me he puesto a reproducir tu problema aquí: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hNCaxx633MGZX91qEza2X/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hNCaxx633MGZX91qEza2X/0), pero he dejado de hacerlo porque considero que podrías facilitarnos los datos y así hacernos más sencillo probar tu consuta y decirte exactamente dónde necesitas cambiar el tipo de unión.

Comment: @OscarGarcia adjunte script de las tablas

Comment: Gracias, ya he visto el problema. No es debido a los `JOIN`, es debido al `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Ese group concat me permirte conocer todos las dimensiones en una sola fila

Comment: Estoy redactando la respuesta sobre como hacerlo correctamente. Dame unos minutos más.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debido a que estás haciendo uso de un `GROUP_CONCAT` sin un `GROUP BY` se supone que quieres hacer una agrupación de **todos los resultados** de la consulta (aunque no haya ninguno), por lo que estás "obligando" a que te devuelva al menos un registro con el resultado de esa agrupación.

Puedes ver este comportamiento en este ejemplo en línea:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5cdvuhHgqFxZUS5FtQkD57/0

---

Explicación del funcionamiento detallada en el manual:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-`NULL` values **from a group**. It returns `NULL` if there are no non-`NULL` values.

En castellano:

> Esta función devuelve una cadena como resultado con la concatenación de todos los valores no-`NULL` **de un grupo**. Devuelve `NULL` si no existen valores no-`NULL`.

Eso último es lo que está ocurriendo. Del resultado completo de la consulta no existe ningún resultado no-`NULL`.

---

Por el contrario, si usamos un `GROUP BY` en el campo adecuado (para que realice una agrupación funcional de datos), en caso de no encontrar ningún registro no aparecerá ningún resultado:

```
SELECT
  productos.id,
  productos.nombre,
  productos.descripcion,
  productos.precio,
  tipos.nombre AS tipo_nombre,
  tipos.id as id_tipo,
  categorias.id as categoria_id,
  categorias.nombre as categoria_nombre,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT( detalle_productos.dimensiones)) AS dimensiones 
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN tipos
  ON productos.id_tipo = tipos.id 
INNER JOIN detalle_productos
  ON productos.id = detalle_productos.id_producto 
INNER JOIN categorias
  ON tipos.id_categoria = categorias.id
WHERE
  productos.id = 1
GROUP BY categorias.id
```

He hecho una agrupación por `categorias.id` para evitar ocultar valores en los `JOIN` posteriores al de la tabla `detalle_productos`.

Comment: Aquí he dejado un ejemplo de la consulta SQL proporcionada: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hNCaxx633MGZX91qEza2X/1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hNCaxx633MGZX91qEza2X/1).

Comment: funcionó perfecto, además de la explicación que es realmente clara, muchas gracias